# Do not render React Component on fresh page load or refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a way to have React not render a component if the page was just loaded or refreshed. The component should only render if the user is browsing from page to page within the single-page application.

I've tried using `window.document.readyState` to detect this but that's been hit or miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Session Storage in the browser like this

```
if(!sessionStorage.active || sessionStorage.active == window.location.href) {
    // First visit or refresh
} else {
    // Render component
}
sessionStorage.active = window.location.href;
```

When the user first visits the page, `sessionStorage.active` will not be set and it will go to `// First visit or refresh`.

If the user refreshes the page, `sessionStorage.active` will be set but it will also equal the current url and go to `// First visit or refresh`.

If the user visits the page from another page within the site, `sessionStorage.active` will be set and it won't match `window.location.href` since it's currently set to the previous visited pages url. Therefore it will go to `// Render component`.

There might be some quirks with this solution that has to be solved for special use cases, but hopefully you have a good starting point.